# Deploying Linux c++ distributable app with third-party libraries

Tags: c++, linux, libraries

I'm developing a cross-platform c++ app and for the time being I'm dealing with getting it work under linux a field that I have little experience of. This app uses third-party libraries like Poco and Boost to name a few.I'm working on a Ubuntu Desktop version where I have built them dynamically and their headers are included in usr/local/include whereas the .so files in usr/local/lib.
If I want to distribute this app is it sufficient to just package my source code (the executable file) + the headers and so files of the third-party libraries or should the receiver of the app to install these libraries on his machine as well for the app to execute?

Comment: Why do you believe that you need to distribute cpp and header files with your application binary?

Comment: To start with, read the licenses of all used libs.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has a few of these things packaged in a few Linux distros: only package your own code, then provide clear documentation which dependencies must be installed to compile and install your own warez. Free brownie points if you provide your own RPM spec file, or whatever APT needs to do the equivalent, as part of your own package.

Comment: @IInspectable  The cpp and h files was wrongfully written I meant only the executable. I'll correct it

Comment: @ deviantfan Regarding the libraries licenses are MIT and Boost Software License which as far I as have understand permit their dynamically linked distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your licenses for the 3rd party code. If it is GPL include the source code tarballs in your download. That's easiest because it doesn't leave you responsible for anything later. Otherwise if Debian / Ubuntu takes it off their archive mirrors six years later you're still liable to produce the source for anyone that asks for it.

Then look into making your code into a stand-alone Linux app. You do this by putting all the shared libraries that you need into your directory. You choose where to define the boundaries. You might decide you can rely on the system's C library, OpenGL, SDL, etc and don't need to bundle those.

Then create a shell script that uses `$0` (that's the `sh` variable that is the full name of the script) to find out where it is running from. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `dirname "$0"` and then `exec realprogram $@`

If you do it this way your code can run on systems a long time into the future. Look at how Quake 3 was packaged for Linux, it was done much like this.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong with this way in my example one can bypass the reading of usr/local/include because I couldn't find a way either in IDE or in Makefile examples that I found to exclude this folder from building procedure